# how to hide text before jTicker animation start?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jTicker for one of my project where there are lots of images, music file and content which take bigger loading time.

My ticker animation was start working before background image loads fully. To prevent that I use below script so that animation wait until image loads fully. It works fine. Now ticker animation start after background image load fully, but the ticking text is now visible before animation start working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
    script.setAttribute("src", "js/jquery.jticker.js")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
})();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jticker.js"></script>
```

Site url : http://websitetesting.us/ei_new/

How to hide ticking text before animation start?

Answer (score 0):

**As you have not provide jticker code**

IMHO you can use [.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) function. Use its callback function for your jticker code

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.getScript("js/jquery.jticker.js", function(){
        // here your jticker code
    })        
});
```